# How to use the react-native app library inside the android app

Tags: android, react-native

i used the "npx react-native-create-library appname" to create the library from react-native application.
Now i want to use this inside the android lib folder how will...

just i want to call the functions from the created react-native library app from any sample android application.

Comment: Your mean is you want to build native module(with UI, function, . . .) or you want to build package and use for any project?

Comment: just want to build package and use only functions in any sample android project.

Comment: if you want to build a native module for Android/iOS and use in your project, just follow React Native - Native Module document for [Android](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) or [iOS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios).

Comment: This we can do but may here requirement is different so can anyone please help to short out this architecture.